# Uniswap V3 Pool initialization

Tags: uniswapv3, liquidity

As I was doing research on Uniswap V3 pool esp. about adding liquidity to such a pool, I found the initialization takes some non-trivial `sqrtPriceX96` that is coming from nowhere. When a pool is getting deployed, isn't the initial price zero when there is no liquidity in it? See this transaction about the initial deployment of ETH-USDC pool on Uniswap V3 for example (https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x144983ea2988f4163aa2794a49e8eb8ef675e1070a9c9d7b2e46215e3089c980) and I have taken the code out to illustrate the point. Thanks.

```
address poolAddr = nonfungiblePositionManager.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
    token0,
    token1, 
    3000, 
    3361342611237137709020779
);
```